# how to split Spark Data Frame in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, split, apache-spark-sql

I am new in Spark for R and I have a large dataset that one column of it is a class type for example my data is like below:

```
      Class Number Value
  1     a      1    100
  2     a      3   1000
  3     b      2    430
  4     c      4    123
  5     c      2     54
  6     c      7      1
```

and I want to split it due to Class types using Spark. for this example I want to obtain 3 spark data frames like this:

## a:

```
      Class Number Value
  1     a      1    100
  2     a      3   1000
```

## b:

```
      Class Number Value
  1     b      2    430
```

## c:

```
      Class Number Value
  1     c      4    123
  2     c      2     54
  3     c      7      1
```

I can apply a `for` and each time filter my data for all of my class types but it takes too much time to be computed in spark. Do you guys have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Are you using sparklyr?